# Get business category from Google+

Tags: java, google-plus, google-places-api

I need to extract the category of a business. I already have the business ID on google+, but I haven't been able to find a method to get the category. Note that Google Places API has a very [general categorization](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types), but I'm in search of the more [detailed one](https://plus.google.com/+CARPETCLEANERSGEELONGOceanGrove/about?hl=en-US).
Is there a way to get that from any google API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the Google Places API currently provides this information and I'm not aware of any other API that does.  You could star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5260) to show your interest in having this feature added to the Google Places API.